# DOMdocument node not being recognized in php

Tags: php, dom

the code below will not work no matter what `Pittsburgh`  is..  the following code

```
if ($elements->item(17)->nodeValue == "Pittsburgh"){echo "hello";}
```

however `echo $elements->item(17)->nodeValue;` will put out: Pittsburgh.

so what gives?

Comment: The value probably contains trailing or leading white spaces. Try `trim($elements->item(17)->nodeValue) === ...`

Comment: it worked.  thank you very much, was wondering though what does the triple === mean?

Comment: `===` is strict equality, which also tests the data type. E.g. `5 == '5'` is `true`, but `5 === '5'` is `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(From my comment as this seems to be the solution)*

The value probably contains trailing or leading white spaces, e.g. if the source XML is:

```
<item>
    Pittsburgh
</item>
```

then the actual value is (`\n` means line break)

```
\n    Pittsburgh\n
```

---

Use  [`trim` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove them:

```
trim($elements->item(17)->nodeValue) === "Pittsburgh"
```